# Is it possible to create a table with an email constraint of '@' The check is to make sure the email has an @ symbol

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

```
CREATE TABLE Member
(
    user_ID              NUMBER NOT NULL ,
    user_password        VARCHAR2(50) NULL  CONSTRAINT  Email_153906048 CHECK (user_password IN ('%@%')),
    user_email           VARCHAR2(50) NULL  CONSTRAINT  Email_1275780631 CHECK (user_email IN ('%@%')),
    user_firstName       VARCHAR2(20) NULL ,
    user_lastName        VARCHAR2(20) NULL ,
    user_type            VARCHAR2(8) NULL  CONSTRAINT  Type_1346517516 CHECK (user_type IN ('Artist', 'Follower')),
CONSTRAINT  XPKUser PRIMARY KEY (user_ID)
);
```

Comment: Those are very strange constraint names - why `Email_1275780631` rather than say `Member_email_check'?

Comment: They were reversed engineered using Erwin. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will check that it contains at least one '@':

```
CHECK (user_email LIKE '%@%')
```

To be sure that there is something on either side of the '@':

```
CHECK (user_email LIKE '%_@_%')
```

More specific checking could be done using regular expressions.

Answer (score 2):

To add to Tony's correct answer, if you decide that you want to do a bit more checking, you can expand on a check constraint with multiple clauses such as:

```
CHECK(
    user_email like '%@%.%'   -- Must contain at least one @ and one subsequent .
and user_email NOT like '%..%'        -- Cannot have two periods in a row
and user_email NOT like '%@%@%'       -- Cannot have two @ anywhere
and user_email NOT like '%.@%'AND user_email NOT like '%@.%' -- Cant have @ and . next to each other
and replace(translate(user_email,'[ &'',":;!=\/()<>]*%','                    '),' ') = user_email -- check for invalid characters
)
```

Don't get too cute with rules though as you don't want to accidentally rule out valid addresses.

Answer (score -1):

Yes. You can create a trigger with a validation checking for the `@` symbol.

Something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER members_bi
BEFORE INSERT
   ON members
   FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   IF INSTR(:new.user_email, '@') = 0 then
      raise_application_error(-20101, 'email must contain AT character');
   end if;
END;

/
```

Comment: Why use a trigger rather than a check constraint?  And what about UPDATE?

Comment: Agree. Didn't know Oracle now supports that kind of constraints. That's why I upvoted you @TonyAndrews